# XSLT change element name - preceding-sibling misunderstood

Tags: xml, html, xslt, xhtml

I wanna change specific **td** to **th** in **xhtml** file if next element's **class is 'xxx'** and then delete this elements (with class 'xxx'), but **preceding-sibling** is wrong in template so I must miss something:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//x:tr[@class='xxx']/preceding-sibling::x:tr/td">
      <th>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </th>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//x:tr[@class='xxx']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:**
sample document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" lang="cs-CZ" xml:lang="cs-CZ">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxx.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="xxx">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>error row to remove if present</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is first row of table as **th** and remove last error row if present and keep HTML5 doctype:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" lang="cs-CZ" xml:lang="cs-CZ">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxx.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I get (with `<xsl:template match="//x:tr[following-sibling::x:tr[1]/@class='xxx']/x:td">` which is now valid in XSLT document):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" lang="cs-CZ" xml:lang="cs-CZ">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxx.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th xmlns="" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1</th>
            <th xmlns="" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">2</th>
            <th xmlns="" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>error row to remove if present</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

So there is no doctype and at th cells are namespaces which would not be there. I don't know howto remove wrong row (it should be always last row).

Comment: How about posting an input sample and the result you want, together with the result you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create new `th` elements in the XHTML namespace then you need to add it to the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="x">

    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:tr[following-sibling::x:tr[1][@class = 'xxx']]/x:td">
        <th>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:tr[@class = 'xxx'] | x:tr[last()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for keeping the DOCTYPE, you would need to create a new one and at least in XSLT 1.0 (which was finalized in 1999 some 15 years before HTML5) all you can do is use `<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>` to output

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

Answer (score 1):

With some gues, I assume something like this may do:

```
<xsl:template match="//x:tr[following-sibling::x:tr[1]/@class='xxx']/x:td">
```

( not tested! )

Comment: Thank you @hr_117 with this modification XSLT document is valid. I've edited post with samples.